# Refresh Flutter App bar with out page refresh

Tags: flutter, page-refresh, bottom-sheet, appbar

I try to create a flutter application UI with the App bar and Bottom sheet. I want to update the app bar item count according to the bottom sheet values. Is there any way to do this?
I want to do it without refresh the page.

Comment: have you used the getx observable?

Comment: @AsimJawad no. I'm not familiar with getx. Can you give me more details

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/get
check here about the getx